# webgl ,after the gl.drawArrays(),the background is gone?

Tags: background, webgl, delay

```
        gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
                

        gl.vertexAttrib3f(position, 0,0,0); 
        setTimeout(()=>{
            gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);
            //the background is gone?why?
            // I've set it up before,gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
            // why zhe background color opacity is 0
        })
```

the background is gone?why?
I've set it up before,gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
why the background color opacity is 0
please help me

Answer (score 0):

he depth, stencil and antialias attributes, when set to true, are requests, not requirements. The WebGL implementation should make a best effort to honor them. When any of these attributes is set to false, however, the WebGL implementation must not provide the associated functionality. Combinations of attributes not supported by the WebGL implementation or graphics hardware shall not cause a failure to create a WebGLRenderingContext. The actual context parameters are set to the attributes of the created drawing buffer. The alpha, premultipliedAlpha and preserveDrawingBuffer attributes must be obeyed by the WebGL implementation.

WebGL presents its drawing buffer to the HTML page compositor immediately before a compositing operation, but only if at least one of the following has occurred since the previous compositing operation:

Context creation
Canvas resize
clear, drawArrays, or drawElements has been called while the drawing buffer is the currently bound framebuffer
Before the drawing buffer is presented for compositing the implementation shall ensure that all rendering operations have been flushed to the drawing buffer. By default, after compositing the contents of the drawing buffer shall be cleared to their default values, as shown in the table above.

This default behavior can be changed by setting the preserveDrawingBuffer attribute of the WebGLContextAttributes object. If this flag is true, the contents of the drawing buffer shall be preserved until the author either clears or overwrites them. If this flag is false, attempting to perform operations using this context as a source image after the rendering function has returned can lead to undefined behavior. This includes readPixels or toDataURL calls, using this context as the source image of another context's texImage2D or drawImage call, or creating an ImageBitmap [HTML] from this context's canvas.